# Find Words include "_" and remove that from word

Tags: c#

I want make C# script that read one txt/csv file and find some special words and change style.
Current format is same this:

```
g_ibuf_160[];
g_ibuf_164[];
gs_168; 
gi_176;
gi_180;
g_datetime_184;
g_datetime_188;
```

Finding words include `_` is easy, but want know how I can change style and remove `_` between characters?
For example:

```
g_ibuf_160[]     convert to  gibuf160[]
or
gi_176           convert to  gi176
or
g_ibuf_160[li_36]     convert to  gibuf160[li36]
```

Regards,

Comment: [String.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Comment: did you actually tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `String.Replace`

```
   string csv = File.ReadAllText(filename).Replace("_", string.Empty);
```